# Recharts: Bar Chart Grouped on XAxis with LineChart on seperate XAxis (different data)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I have a barchart displaying groups of bars for each month in a 3 month period.

[image: grouped bar chart with added line]

I have now been asked to add a line chart with the daily views spanning the 3 month period to chart like this (the red line i've drawn in the below image is the linechart of views):

[image: grouped bar chart with added line]

I have tried several strategies, and all of them were unsuccessful. I'm currently at a loss to how i should approach this, and any ideas are appreciated. if worse comes to worse, i can always render two seperate charts and absolutely position one above the other, but i thought i'd try here for suggestions before resorting to that. I am not above changing my data structure, so long as i can keep the bar's grouped by month, and plot the line linearly over the 3 month period

The data structure i am currently using is something like below:

```
[
  [
    {
      "month": "May",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 3,
        "value": 35
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 13,
        "value": 61
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 17,
        "value": 193
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 12,
        "value": 164
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "June",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 22,
        "value": 203
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 6,
        "value": 31
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 21,
        "value": 231
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 19,
        "value": 30
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "July",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 16,
        "value": 196
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 16,
        "value": 107
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 13,
        "value": 59
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 2,
        "value": 175
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "month": "May",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 20,
        "value": 25
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 21,
        "value": 104
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 14,
        "value": 124
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 1,
        "value": 164
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "June",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 10,
        "value": 168
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 16,
        "value": 128
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 14,
        "value": 79
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 8,
        "value": 187
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "July",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 21,
        "value": 136
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 9,
        "value": 241
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 20,
        "value": 29
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 0,
        "value": 56
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "month": "May",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 7,
        "value": 212
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 19,
        "value": 90
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 6,
        "value": 175
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 6,
        "value": 66
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "June",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 8,
        "value": 179
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 12,
        "value": 81
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 9,
        "value": 200
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 2,
        "value": 236
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "July",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 10,
        "value": 200
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 4,
        "value": 105
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 17,
        "value": 188
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 8,
        "value": 77
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "month": "May",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 17,
        "value": 148
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 16,
        "value": 152
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 24,
        "value": 79
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 12,
        "value": 129
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "June",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 17,
        "value": 202
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 3,
        "value": 132
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 15,
        "value": 186
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 15,
        "value": 105
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "July",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 11,
        "value": 83
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 19,
        "value": 192
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 6,
        "value": 114
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 2,
        "value": 109
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "month": "May",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 9,
        "value": 104
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 24,
        "value": 54
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 17,
        "value": 60
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 1,
        "value": 108
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "June",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 6,
        "value": 80
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 22,
        "value": 214
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 23,
        "value": 38
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 15,
        "value": 156
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "July",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 21,
        "value": 247
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 16,
        "value": 72
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 17,
        "value": 158
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 12,
        "value": 74
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "month": "May",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 2,
        "value": 193
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 6,
        "value": 250
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 18,
        "value": 167
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 20,
        "value": 98
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "June",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 25,
        "value": 84
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 21,
        "value": 212
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 0,
        "value": 172
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 14,
        "value": 246
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "July",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 14,
        "value": 90
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 6,
        "value": 47
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 7,
        "value": 234
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 14,
        "value": 181
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "month": "May",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 10,
        "value": 140
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 1,
        "value": 112
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 20,
        "value": 191
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 12,
        "value": 58
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "June",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 2,
        "value": 250
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 14,
        "value": 109
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 16,
        "value": 159
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 12,
        "value": 89
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "July",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 24,
        "value": 46
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 6,
        "value": 189
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 11,
        "value": 197
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 19,
        "value": 179
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "month": "May",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 19,
        "value": 52
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 11,
        "value": 86
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 2,
        "value": 63
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 17,
        "value": 133
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "June",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 9,
        "value": 225
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 1,
        "value": 68
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 23,
        "value": 220
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 7,
        "value": 124
      }
    },
    {
      "month": "July",
      "messages": {
        "name": "messages",
        "growth": 9,
        "value": 171
      },
      "views": {
        "name": "views",
        "growth": 1,
        "value": 221
      },
      "shares": {
        "name": "shares",
        "growth": 22,
        "value": 191
      },
      "favorites": {
        "name": "favorites",
        "growth": 4,
        "value": 95
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

And the code for rendering my chart is:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, 
    Tooltip, LabelList, Legend, ResponsiveContainer
} from 'recharts';

const labels = {
    messages:'Messages',
    views:'Views',
    shares:'Shares',
    favorites:'Favorites'
};

const legendFormatter = (value,entry,index) => labels[value.split('.')[0]];
const tooltipFormatter = (value,name,props) => [value,legendFormatter(name)]

const renderCustomizedLabel = (fill) =>{
    return (props) => {
        const { x, y, width, value } = props;

        console.log(props)

        return (
            <g>
                <rect width={width} height={30} x={x} y={y-30}  fill="#fff" />
                <text x={x + width / 2} y={y - 12} fill={fill} textAnchor="middle" dominantBaseline="middle">
                {value > 0 ?('+'+value):value}
                </text>
            </g>
        );
    };
};

const RenderChart = ({data})=>(<ResponsiveContainer height={400}>
    <BarChart data={data}
        style={{ backgroundColor:'#F4F4F4' }}
        margin={{ top: 45, right: 20, left: -10, bottom: 15 }}
    >
        <XAxis dataKey="month" />
        <YAxis/>
        <Tooltip formatter={tooltipFormatter} />
        <Legend formatter={legendFormatter} />
        <Bar dataKey="messages.value" fill="#4A8A95" minPointSize={5}>
            <LabelList dataKey="messages.growth" content={renderCustomizedLabel('#4A8A95')} />
        </Bar>
        <Bar dataKey="views.value" fill="#FBBE52" minPointSize={5}>
            <LabelList dataKey="views.growth" content={renderCustomizedLabel('#FBBE52')} />
        </Bar>
        <Bar dataKey="shares.value" fill="#EA4646" minPointSize={5}>
            <LabelList dataKey="shares.growth" content={renderCustomizedLabel('#EA4646')} />
        </Bar>
        <Bar dataKey="favorites.value" fill="#0467BA" minPointSize={5}>
            <LabelList dataKey="favorites.growth" content={renderCustomizedLabel('#0467BA')} />
        </Bar>
    </BarChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>);
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://recharts.org/en-US/api/ComposedChart?

Comment: @Sunil i have tried doing it with a composed chart, but i couldn't come up with a way to do what i wanted with it. So i am asking if anyone else knows how to do it.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I want to achieve same as well.

Comment: @AliRehman no, unfortunately i never did. we ended up just stacking the charts one on top of each other.